# Is there any way to instantiate MIDI devices on iPhone/iPad accessible through standard USB connector?

Tags: ipad, ios4, midi

When an iPad is plugged into a Mac with the normal white USB-30 pin connector cable, I would like to be able to send MIDI messages from an app on the Mac to an app running on the iPad through that cable rather than either network MIDI or the special MIDI (camera connection) interface.

Can this be done? I can imagine writing special purpose glue MIDI devices on both the Mac and the iPad that know how to move data through the cable and then present it as MIDI at each end but I was hoping not to have to go to that trouble.

I don't want to use wifi as I don't want to have to start creating adhoc connections between my mac and the ipad during live performance gigs (in particular, I don't even want wifi enabled on the mac when involved in live performance). The camera connection kit which apparently can support MIDI doesn't seem to have support for power and the other concern is that the iPad battery would die in the middle of a performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the iConnectMIDI will help you. Please have a look at http://iconnectivity.eu

Answer (score 0):

Early versions of AirDisplay worked via the USB wire, until Apple made them remove that feature. I don't know how they did it, but I suspect it was via the [external accessory framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502). Alternatively, it might be possible via the (private) IOKit framework. If you're using this app for your own personal purposes and don't plan to submit to the app store, those could be viable solutions.

Comment: Actually, I solved the issue by adding a little wireless router to my live rig. It's connected by ethernet to my laptop and various other musical devices and by wifi to the iPad. The mac itself has wifi disabled completely.